# I want to have a title centered on the same line as two floats one to left and one to right

Tags: html, css

You misunderstood me in my previous message so I post a new with an example.
Assume the following that you float for example an image left and some div to the right containing for example which browser you use and date + time and some other things perhaps.

Now you want also to display a name for the company centered between these two floats on the same row. The text of the company in between should always be centered even when you make the browser width smaller.

In this example I can't make the text to be placed centered between the two floats.
It doesn't matter if I put the text in inline element or block element.
I have tried both. In this example I have a p tag.

It doesn't work to use text-align:centered when you have elements that are floating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset = "utf-8">
       <title></title>
       <style type = "text/css">
           #imageone 
           {
              float:left;
           }
           p#right
           {
              float:right;
           }
           div p
           {
              text-align  : center;
           }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div style="background:red">
          <p>My company</p>
          <p id="right">2013-06-12 10:00:12</p>
          <img id="imageone" src="img/die1.png" alt="photo" />
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of the problem, because when I try, it centers the company name just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your company name after the floated elements in the html:

```
<body>
   <div style="background:red">

      <p id="right">2013-06-12 10:00:12</p>
      <img id="imageone" src="img/die1.png" alt="photo" />
        <p id="name">My company</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Adding margin 0 to p#right also ensures it will appear vertically centered with the other elements:

```
#imageone 
       {
          float:left;
       }
       p#right
       {
          float:right;
            margin: 0;
       }
       div #name
       {
          text-align  : center;

       }

}
```

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WDrVK/1/

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple to do if any two of the elements are fixed-width.  You can implement it by using `position: relative` on the containing element, and `position: absolute` on the children (the blocks to be aligned left, right, and center).

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsNu2/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you style the center element as `margin: 0 auto;`?

As in this example: http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html